# Finding electric flux due to charges through a sphere

Tags: electrostatics

**Problem:**
Two charges of magnitudes $-2Q$ and $+Q$ are located at points $(a,0)$ and $(4a, 0)$ respectively. What is the electric flux due to these charges through a sphere of radius '$3a$' with its center at the origin?

**Solution:**
Using Gauss's law,
$Flux(ϕ)=q/ ϵ0$,
Where $q$ is the total charge inside the surface and $ϵ0$ is the permittivity of free space.
So, $Flux(ϕ)=−2Q/ϵ0$

**Doubt:**
How can we find the solution for the same using the formula:
$Φ = E⋅S = EScosθ$
Where $E$ is the magnitude of the electric field, $S$ is the area of the surface, and $θ$ is the angle between the electric field lines and the normal (perpendicular) to S.

Comment: You need to calculate the  integral of $E.dS$, as both $E$ and $dS$ change with position

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just calculate the flux manually as it were. For example, flux is given as:
$$\text{Flux}=\oint\vec E\cdot \mathbf{\hat n}\;dA.$$
So the expression for the field is:
$$\vec E(\vec r)=-k{2Q\over |\vec r-(a\mathbf{\hat x})|^3}(\vec r-(a\mathbf{\hat x}))+k{Q\over |\vec r-(4a\mathbf{\hat x})|^3}(\vec r-(4a\mathbf{\hat x})).$$
Since the closed surface in question is a sphere, we can find the form of $\mathbf{\hat n}$ easily enough. It is the radially outward unit vector which is given by:
$$\mathbf{\hat n}=\cos(\theta)\mathbf{\hat x}+\sin(\theta)\mathbf{\hat y}.$$
And Gauss' law tells you that the external charge doesn't contribute to the flux, so you can neglect its contribution to the overall field so that $\vec E(\vec r)$ becomes:
$$\vec E(\vec r)=-k{2Q\over |\vec r-(a\mathbf{\hat x})|^3}(\vec r-(a\mathbf{\hat x})).$$
So plugging this stuff in we get:
$$\begin{align}
\text{Flux}&=\oint -k{2Q\over |\vec r-(a\mathbf{\hat x})|^3}(\vec r-(a\mathbf{\hat x}))\cdot [\cos(\theta)\mathbf{\hat x}+\sin(\theta)\mathbf{\hat y}] \;dA\\
&=\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} -k{2Q(3a-\cos(\theta))9a^2\sin(\phi)\over [9a^2(1+a^2-2a\cos(\theta)]^{3/2}}\;d\theta d\phi\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi} k{4Q(3a-\cos(\theta))9a^2\over [9a^2(1+a^2-2a\cos(\theta)]^{3/2}}\;d\theta .
\end{align}
$$
And the rest I leave as an exercise, it is mainly a matter of simplifying enough so that one can find a suitable integral formula to perform the integration.